# can slack custom command trigger other slash commands?

Tags: slack-api

I'd like to create a slack command like `/byebye` that first triggers a `/giphy peace i'm out of here` command and then triggers a `/leave` command in the same channel. From the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/), its pretty clear how to create new commands, but its not obvious how to chain other commands within a custom slash command (if its even possible to do). Can you trigger other slash commands inside of a custom slash command and, if so, how do you do it?

Comment: You can issue commands through the Slack API with an undocumented method. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830215/4379151) for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you invoke the /poll command using the Slack API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919745/how-do-you-invoke-the-poll-command-using-the-slack-api)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like TextExpander to automate this. You could send both commands with the return keys and everything all from a single client-side command.

Comment: interesting idea. the trick is that i'd like to cache (server-side) a bunch of clever ways of saying 'goodbye' so that people that `/leave` rooms can do so in style.