# How do you invoke the /poll command using the Slack API?

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

My slack channel supports the `/poll` command from the Simple Poll app. How do you invoke this command using the Slack API?

Using the [python slack(er) API module](https://github.com/os/slacker):

```
from slacker import Slacker

# Using what's now called a "legacy token"
slack = Slacker('my-token')

slack.chat.post_message(
        '#test',
        '/poll "Do you prefer cats or dogs?" "Cats" "Dogs"',
        as_user=False,
        username="Poll Bot",
        icon_emoji=':question:',
        parse='full')
```

The message just shows up in the #test channel as plain text, not converted to a poll.

I tried using `<!poll>` instead of `/poll` in the message, as sort of implied in the [message formatting documenation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting), but same result.

Note: This question is a bit old now, and upon revisiting I have found out that my code is using what's now called a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens), which doesn't allow specifying any [OAuth permission scopes](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes). The legacy token already has the permissions it needs for this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use the "undocumented" [`chat.command`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md) API function instead of `chat.postMessage`. This function is a little less friendly with the `channel` parameter -- you have to provide the channel ID and not the human-friendly channel name.

```
channel_id = slack.channels.get_channel_id('test')
slack.chat.command(
        channel=channel_id,
        command='/poll',
        text='"Do you prefer cats or dogs?" "Cats" "Dogs"'
)
```

Thanks to [V13Axel in this Wee-Slack bug tracker](https://github.com/rawdigits/wee-slack/issues/227) for providing some debugging info for the `chat.command` that clued me in.

According to @Erik_Kalkoken's [unofficial documentation](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md), `chat.command`

> requires the scope `post`. Since this scope does not seem to be available in the app config window you need to provide a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) for this to work.

Comment: This appears to be another undocumented API command. Many thanks for sharing.

Comment: I am maintaining a github repo to document "undocumented" Slack API methods - [link](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc)  - and I have taken the liberty to add this method to it. Any comment or further input on the documentation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This does not seem to be working anymore. At least not with the python slack-client sc.api_call("chat.command", channel=channel, command=slash_command, text=message)

Comment: @mschmidt42 I haven't looked into the slack package you mentioned, but it's still working for me with the `slacker` package. What error are you getting?

Comment: @mschmidt42 The channel must be by id,  the command must have %2F before the slash_command, and you have to pass an authentication token

Comment: @CivFan While trying the same snippet, I am getting a missing scope error. What is the scope required for chat.command to work? I have tried both chat:write:bot & chat:write:user

Comment: @ritz I was using what's now called a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens). You can't specify scopes on this kind of token.

Comment: @ritz I think this requires a legacy token unfortunately. I added a note with a quote from Erik's unofficial documentation.

Comment: Is it still possible to send the /poll command? Because Im getting an "unkown_command" error

Comment: @zwep Sorry I don't have my environment or code to test this anymore. It's possible `/poll` was dropped. Or you need to install a plugin.

Comment: @CivFan thanks for the info! I'll fix something myself

Answer (score 3):

I was stumbling across the exact same problem, so I did a bit of coding and a working example is here:

https://github.com/dazlious/slack-cmd-trigger

You can trigger with your api-token any channel with a command.

Comment: This is so amazing!! I am trying to use this with "/giphy" but the user has to click on "Send" for posting the gif. Do you know if we can achieve it using the command line?