# Does slack have a method for triggering a command?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I built a slackbot for my startup. I would like to trigger things like `/poll`. Using `client.chat_postMessage` posts rather as plain text without triggering the command. I tried to follow [How do you invoke the /poll command using the Slack API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919745/how-do-you-invoke-the-poll-command-using-the-slack-api), but of no use since that method doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain types of interaction triggers provided by slack:

1. Interactions that happen on a schedule
2. Interactions initiated by external services
3. Events API pushes
4. User invocation

https://api.slack.com/interactivity#triggers

Since you have mentioned about `chat.PostMessage`, 
you might want to look into **Interactivity in Block Kit (User Invokation)**

 https://api.slack.com/block-kit/interactivity